# Can I use an EIDE ATA-133 hard drive in a server that uses SATA?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, ide

I have an old 160 GB EIDE ATA-133 hard drive, which I would like to use in my Dell PowerEdge T105 server.

However, the cables inside the T105 are SATA, which won't connect to the drive.

Is there some way I can connect this? Are there adapter cables available? Or do I need to buy some additional hardware for the server to use this drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find PCI PATA adapters for reasonable prices, usually cheaper than a SATA-to-PATA adapter.

Comment: I am thinking this may do the trick: http://www.amazon.com/PATA-to-SATA-Device-Adapter/dp/B001JQHJSU
any idea?

Comment: That one goes the wrong way. Try this instead: http://www.amazon.com/SATA-IDE-Drive-Interface-Adapter/dp/B002PN8B1A/ref=pd_cp_e_1